# Issues with PHP to extract MySQL database into table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to produce code to use php embedded in html to extract information from a database into a table.

```
<div class="entry">
 <?php
  $host="localhost";
  $user="";
  $password="";
  $dbname = "";
  mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM QA";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  print '<table="1">';
  print   '<tr>';
  print        '<th>...</th>';
  print        '<th>Questions and Answers</th>';
  print    '</tr>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>Question</td>'
    print '<td>'.$row['question'].'</a></td>'
    print '</tr>';
    print '<tr>';
    print '<td>Answer:</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row['answer'].'</a></td>'
    print '</tr>';
  }
  print '</table>';  
  mysql_close();
  ?>
  </div>
```

The output looks like this.

> '; print ''; print '...'; print 'Questions and Answers'; print ''; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { print ''; print 'Question' print ''.$row['question'].'' print ''; print ''; print 'Answer:'; print ''.$row['answer'].'' print ''; } print ''; mysql_close(); ?>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use deprecated functions

Comment: No, this is valid `print "Hello world";` @LouisXIV

Comment: Almost seems obvious that if your output is actual "code" instead of an HTML output, that your file may not have the `.php` extension or your server's not setup for PHP or not properly configured/installed. Plus you also have a stray variable `$info`

Comment: `$info = mysql_fetch_array($result);` For what?

Comment: You probably meant to use `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($info))` but again, even that shouldn't show you raw PHP output.

Comment: OK, the problem was I didn't have a php extension. But now all I get is a blank screen.

Comment: PHP is configured because I have gotten it to upload to the database with the same mysql connection.

Comment: Tried echo, deleted the unused $info, still nothing. Does it need the <?php before <html>(though tried with and without). Is my MySQL ok? I have a table QA with columns inculding question and answer. So ".$row['question']." will call the question column?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="entry">
 <?php
  $host="localhost";
  $user="";
  $password="";
  $dbname = "";
  mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");
  $query = "SELECT * FROM QA";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo '<table="1">';
  echo   '<tr>';
  echo        '<th>...</th>';
  echo        '<th>Questions and Answers</th>';
  echo    '</tr>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Question</td>'
    echo '<td>'.$row['question'].'</a></td>'
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>Answer:</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['answer'].'</a></td>'
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';  
  mysql_close();
  ?>
  </div>
```

Try this I believe it's due to PRINT